# Could not resolve property error while selecting from a association table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to make a select from a association table (from 2 table having many to many relationship). Here are my entities:

Question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

@Id
private int id;

@Column(name = "question_text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "chapter_id")
private int chapterId;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions")
  @Transient
  public Set<Assessment> assessments = new HashSet<Assessment>();

public Question(int id, String text, int chapterId) {

    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.chapterId =chapterId;
}
//getters setters
```

Assessment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assessment")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Assessment {


@Id
private int id;
private String name;

@Column(name = "chapter_id")
private int chapterId;
private int grade;
private String type;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "assessment_question", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "assessment_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "question_id") }
    )
    @Transient
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Question.class)
    Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>();

public Assessment(int id, String name, int chapterId, int grade, String type) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
    this.grade=grade;
    this.type=type;
}
//getters & setters
```

In MySQL schema, these 2 entities have an association table assessment_question, having both `assessment_id` and `question_id` as keys.

I'm trying to read the entries from this table. This is the DAO method:

```
@Transactional
    public List<Question> getQuestionsOfAssessment(int id) {

        List<Question> list = null;

        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Question.class);

        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try{

            TypedQuery<Question> query=sf.openSession().createQuery("select q from Question q join q.assessments a where a.id = :id"); 
                    query.setParameter("id",id);

            list = query.getResultList();

            tx.commit();  
            session.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return list;
        }
```

However, I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: assessments of: models.Question [select q from models.Question q join q.assessments a where a.id = :id]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
at dao.AssessmentQuestionDAO.getQuestionsOfAssessment(AssessmentQuestionDAO.java:60)
at webapp.Main.main(Main.java:156)
```

I read a lot here around about how to use many to many and how to solve this but nothing could solve it so far. It looks like I'm missing some very minor thing probably that I cannot see. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: `@Transient` is wrong there

Comment: taking it out gives me an error like ```Exception in thread main org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: models.Question.assessments[models.Assessment]```.I tried to solve this before and got the suggestion of adding ```@Transient```.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: this is the exact tutorial that I followed when I created the mapping between the classes. Checked everything once more now, still no success

Comment: What imports do you use?

Comment: everything is from javax.persistence: 
```import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;```

Comment: I solved now! I modified the next line (added both annotated classes, as opposed to just the Question class as before): 
```Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Question.class).addAnnotatedClass(Assessment.class);```

Comment: Then remove the unnecessary annotations (`@Transient` and `@ElementCollection`). Then also check your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and make sure to add `Assessment` as mapped class